# what's the unmount process for refs in react?

Tags: reactjs

I saw code like this:

```js
export class Editor extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.formElements = {
         name: { label: "Name", name: "name", validation: { required: true, minLength: 3 } /*element: HTMLElement*/ },
         category: { label: "Category", name: "category", validation: { required: true, minLength: 5 } /*element: HTMLElement*/ },
      };

   }

   setElement = (element) => {   // <---------------why null check here?
      if (element !== null) {  
         this.formElements[element.name].element = element;  
      }
   }

   // ...

   render() {
      return <React.Fragment>
         {
            Object.values(this.formElements).map(elem => 
               <div className="form-group p-2" key={elem.name}>
                  <label>{elem.label}</label>
                  <input className="form-control" name={elem.name} autoFocus={elem.name === "name"} ref={this.setElement}/>
              
               </div>
            )
         }      
      </React.Fragment>
   }
}
```

I don't understand why we need to do the null check here:

```js
setElement = (element) => {  
   if (element !== null) {  // <-----------------
         this.formElements[element.name].element = element;  
   }
}
```

because when I toggle the checkbox to re-render, I understand the original "name" input is destroyed and a new one is created, but when the original input is about to be destroyed , why react is designed to call `setElement()` again? shouldn't react just ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Manipulating the DOM with a ref](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref) documentation:

> React will set the `current` property back to `null` when the node is removed from the screen.

The `null` check means the code wants to keep the input DOM node inside the `this.formElements` object, even if the `input` element has been unmounted(the DOM node has been removed from the document)